# Excel: how to make each cell of a row equal to other cells of a row but jumping by 2 cells instead of 1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: screenshot1]
How can I create a formula that I can drag that makes the values in row 37 correspond to the values in row 32, which doesn't jump 1 cell, but 2 at a time. In other words, to get in row 37 the value corresponding to the cell that has the same color in row 32, as shown in the screenshot.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: IF the Column Headers in row 31 are matched in Row 36 then simply use a SUMIF: =SUMIF(31:31,J36,32:32) -- Doesn't matter if it jumps 2 rows then.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
=INDEX(32:32,,(COLUMN()-10)*2+17)
```

in cell J37 and drag that across.

Comment: cool @AnkeRojićBecker - if it is the answer, then please mark it as the answer.